# How to use external .h and .o files in current project with Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, linker

I was given three files to test my project: `Test1.cpp` `SignalMasker.h` and `SignalMasker.o` when `Test1.cpp` includes the `SignalMasker.h` file and files from my project. Putting both in the source folder returns undefined references such as:

```
error: undefined reference to 'SignalMasker::~SignalMasker()'
```

I tried to use the project preferences and add the .o file to it. Under `GCC C++ Linker-> Miscellaneous -> other objects`. When selecting a file it inserted a new record as:

```
"${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/source/SignalMasker.o}"
```

Building it didn't seem to resolve the issue so I added to the `Linker flags` the `-l` flag and got:

```
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -l -o "uthreads"  ./source/Scheduler.o ./source/SchedulerStarter.o ./source/Test1.o ./source/Thread.o ./source/main.o ./source/uthreads.o  /home/tom/workspace/uthreads/source/SignalMasker.o 
g++: error: uthreads: No such file or directory
make: *** [uthreads] Error 1
```

So I went back to `other objects` and replaced the automatic generated variable to:

```
./source/SignalMasker.o
```

And building gave me:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `source/SignalMasker.o', needed by `uthreads'.  Stop.
```

These are all solutions I've found in SO and none seem to work including making a library and trying to include it. Please help.

**EDIT**: `uthreads` is also the name of the project.

Comment: the -l flag specifies a library to link with, on its own is meaningless. try removing it

Comment: @krsteeve same last error

Comment: Can you show us the makefile you're using?

Comment: @krsteeve Eclipse is generate the makefile behind the scenes and deleting it when it fails to build the project

Comment: You say "building and running it didn't resolve the issue". I'm curious how you were able to run without getting past linking.

Comment: @krsteeve my mistake, I wasn't running it.

Comment: So everything you did before adding -l seemed correct. (putting it in other objects) - there must be a problem with the path you're using. It can't find the .o file